# How To Capture MySQL Information In Log From Command Line

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to log all output from my query into a file, but I'm only getting partial information.

Here is my alter file:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword db -v -c --show-warnings -e \
"alter table A engine=InnoDB;

alter table B engine=InnoDB;

alter table C engine=InnoDB;

alter table D engine=InnoDB;"
```

And this is the current output:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
--------------
alter table A engine=InnoDB
--------------

--------------
alter table B engine=InnoDB
--------------

--------------
alter table C engine=InnoDB
--------------

--------------
alter table D engine=InnoDB
```

---

However, I'm trying to mimic the output that I would get if I were logged into the mysql command line, which is the following:

```
mysql> source alter.sql
Database changed
--------------
alter table A engine=InnoDB
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
alter table B engine=InnoDB
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.18 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
alter table C engine=InnoDB
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.51 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

--------------
alter table D engine=InnoDB
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Normally I would run a screen session so I can capture this information, however that is not an available option for my current situation. But I have several queries that are running and I need timings for each individual query as well as any warning or ERROR information.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql --tee myoutputfile` when you start the client.

Or you can start saving the output from within a session with the `tee` command and turn off saving output with `notee`. (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html).

---

As @gview commented below, I learned that `tee` does not work in batch mode. I had never come across that before. I don't know any way of doing what you want in the mysql client. You may have to write your own client.

Comment: When I change my script to the following: 'mysql --tee output.log...' it produced an empty output.log file

Comment: --tee option doesn't work in batch mode.